# Why $\nu(E)=\int_E fd\mu$ is a signed measure.

Tags: measure-theory

I don't understand a concept. A signed measure $\nu$ on a $\sigma -$\algebra is a mapping that satisfy

1) The set function $\nu$ is extended valued in the sense that $-\infty <\nu(E)\leq \infty $ for all $E\in\mathcal M$.

2) If $\{E_i\}_i$ are disjoint subset of $\mathcal M$, then $$\nu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \nu(E_j).$$

**Example**
If $f\geq 0$ and $f$ is $\mu-$measurable, then
$$\nu(E)=\int_E f d\mu$$
where $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ is a measure space is a signed measure.

**Question**

How can $\int_E fd\mu <0$ if $f\geq 0$ ?

Comment: What if $\mu$ is a signed measure?

Comment: There's one more condition to the signed measure: The series on the LHS must converge absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

The measure $\nu$ you defined is a signed measure because every positive measure is a signed measure.  Every "normal" measure you've been exposed to satisfies the two criteria you listed for signed measure, so every "normal" (i.e., positive) measure is a signed measure.

But we don't have to restrict ourselves to $f \geq 0$.  Let $f$ be any $L^{1}$ function.  Then $\nu_{1}(E) := \int \limits_{E} f\,d\mu$ is a signed measure.  Clearly, if $K$ is any measurable set with $f(x) < 0$ on $K$, then $\nu_{1}(K) \leq 0$.

Comment: I think we don't necessarily need to assume $f\in \mathcal{L}^1$, as long as $\int f d\mu$ exists.... correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @JoZ Thank you for your comment. :) You're right that you can relax the $L^{1}$ condition to obtain a non-finite signed measure, please see the examples section of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure